# Visibility with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm new to angular and have this simple problem.
I have a button,when i click i want to show a grid and some filters that are invisble.The filters are like this.

```
<div ng-show="filtroFilial" style="visibility: hidden" class="col-md-2">
   <div class="form-group">
      <label>Estado da Filial</label>
      <div class="form-group form-md-line-input  no-hint right" style="padding-top: 3px;">
         <select id="regional" name="regional" chosen width="150" allow-single-deselect="true" ng-model="vm.relatorio.regional" style="width:100%"
            ng-options="regional.Cod_Regional as regional.Nom_Regional for regional in vm.regionais | orderBy:'Nom_Regional'" ></select>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

And the grid is like this.(The beggining)

```
<div id="divSilt" style="overflow-x: hidden;">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
<div class="portlet light form-fit bordered" style="padding: 10px 20px 0 20px;">
<div class="portlet-body form">
<div class="tabbable tabbable-tabdrop">
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
```

This is my screen.[image]

When i click "Aplicar Filtros" i want to show everthing that was hidden. I use 
ng-show or just ID ? This is my .js,

```
vm.filtrar = function() {
    $scope.$parent.vm.loading = $http({
        method: 'Post',
        url: _obterUrlAPI() + "AcompanhamentoSilt/FiltroSilt",
        dataType: "jsonp"
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        vm.importacaoSilt = response.data;
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
        MessageBox("Erro", response.data.Message);
    });
};
```

if the return is sucess i want to show everything that will be like this.How can change the visibility?Is in the js i put above?

[image]

Comment: Why are you adding visibilty hidden to a div with an ng-show?

Comment: just put `scope.showOthers = false` before your http. and then in your http once you have successfuly got your information change `scope.showOthers = true` and then in div `ng-show = showOthers`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All that you need to do is add an `ng-show="false"`.

Then all you need to do is add an `ng-click` to a button that changes the variable that is showing/hiding the div. so in other words you should have something like this:

```
<div ng-show="showMe">
    this is hidden on load
</div>
```

And in your controller:

```
$scope.showMe = false;
```

This means your div is hidden when the page loads. Now you call a funtion to show the div

```
<button ng-click="showAll()"></button>
```

And in your controller

```
$scope.showAll = function(){
    $scope.showMe = true;
}
```

This will change the variable which shows/hide the div.

Comment: Cool. Happy coding!